# How to reset variable value to its default value in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code

```vb
Sub colourcode()
    Dim tcol As Integer, ro As Integer, co As Integer

    ro = 2
    co = 2

    tcol = 10

    For i = 1 To tcol
    Cells(ro, co).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    ro = ro + 2
     Next

'I want to reset a variable ro value to its default value which is 2.

    End Sub
```

Comment: reset it to what/what triggers it?

Comment: You mean after the loop finishes, set `ro` back to where it started? If so, short answer is `ro = 2`. Slightly longer answer if you're not sure where it started, you could go with `ro = ro - (tcol * 2)`

Comment: `ro` and `co` will cease to exist where the comment is?  Do you mean a static start point for loops in future, or is there more code after the comment in this sub?

Comment: I want to add some more code after this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to minimize your maintenance issues use a constant for the starting point:

```
Sub colourcode()

    Const RO_START As Long = 2
    'any other fixed value...

    Dim tcol As Long, ro As Long, co As Long

    ro = RO_START
    co = 2
    tcol = 10

    For i = 1 To tcol
        ActiveSheet.Cells(ro, co).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        ro = ro + 2
    Next

    ro = RO_START  'reset, avoiding repeating the 2

End Sub
```